# How extract subsets from string in bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a string variable consisting of 4 parts looking either something like this:

```
social_CA_FR_bloom_build
```

or this:

```
 social_DE_bloom_trgj4_67
```

(and different variations of this).

How would I write a regex in BigQuery to extract the subsets so I can build new columns containing the first part (social), second part `(CA_FR or DE etc`), third part (bloom) and fourth part (t`rgj4_67 or build, etc`)?

I've already tried this:

```
regexp_extract(field, "([^_]+)_([A-Z]{2}[_A-Z]*)_([^_]+)_(.+)", 1)
```

which works in SQL (hive), but not in BQ as it doesn't recognize (string, string, integer).

I was thinking of replacing the underscore between CA_FR (which should be kept together and only occurs in a couple of rows, normally it's just two capitals) with a hyphen and then using SPLIT on the string instead of a regex_extract, but I'm not sure how to go about this/if this is the solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to apply a regular expression and then use `SPLIT`. For example:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS social,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS language,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS bloom,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS build
FROM (
  SELECT
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(
            label,
            r'([^_]+)_([A-Z]{2}[_A-Z]*)_([^_]+)_(.+)',
            r'\1|\2|\3|\4'),
          '|') AS parts
  FROM YourTable
);
```

I made up the column names--you can use whichever names you want. As a self-contained example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 'social_CA_FR_bloom_build' AS label UNION ALL
  SELECT 'social_DE_bloom_trgj4_67' AS label
)
SELECT
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS social,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS language,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS bloom,
  parts[SAFE_OFFSET(3)] AS build
FROM (
  SELECT
    SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(
            label,
            r'([^_]+)_([A-Z]{2}[_A-Z]*)_([^_]+)_(.+)',
            r'\1|\2|\3|\4'),
          '|') AS parts
  FROM YourTable
);
```